# formulating a proof about concatenation of motions

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be any motion $$ A: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $$
$$||A(x)-A(y)|| = ||x-y|| $$

and $B$ an 'actual' motion. The difference between A and B is that $ det(A)= 1 $ and  $ det( B) =-1 $. You can also define it as $ A=T \circ U$. With $T$ beeing a translation and $U$ an orthogonal linear projection.
The 'actual' motion beeing a motion just on the plane where you don't have to fold the plane.
I coulnd't find the english name for it.

I have two similiar tasks I want to prove:

i) $A^{-1} \circ B \circ A $ is an 'actual' motion

ii) Let be $T$ a translation. Than $A^{-1} \circ T \circ A $ is also a translation.

My issue now is to find I don't know how to solve them formally..
both statements are clear. If you concatenate a motion with a translation and then again with the inverse of the motion ofc you get back a translation.
How do I formulate it mathematically?
Any help is appreciated !

Comment: How do you define the determinant $\det A$ if i$A$ is a mix of rotations and translations?